# Objective-c: How to detect double tap on view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am developing an application where I have multiple controls on view but I want to enable them when user double tap the view

You can take the example of double click but in device I want to catch the event when their is double tap.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view which you want to be tapped.

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Comment: in case of the existence of multiple gesture recognizers, you can ensure the double tap one of "high priority" by using: [self.view.tapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.doubleTapGestureRecognizer];

Comment: don't forget to add the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to your class private interface ... @interface IBMYourClassName ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Answer (score 8):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view, with `numberOfTapsRequired = 2`.

Comment: is UITapGestureRecognizer a control? Its not in controls Library

Comment: It's a UIGestureRecognizer subclass. You need to write it in code.

Comment: I write this code with selector and UIAlert but it doesnot work
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
 
    [tapGesture release];
 
}

Comment: Did you add it to the view using addGestureRecognizer: ?